# Java Android - CSVWriter calculate math formula with specific cells

Tags: java, android, csv

I'm using CSVWriter to write to a csv a list of data.

Is it possible for me to pick a specific cell and create a mathematical formula to be calculated?

For example, I would like cell D5 to calculate the addition of cell A1 + B2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are messing a little with CSV format - it's not the format with cells and formulas - it's just an array of rows which have values separated usually by comma / semicolon.

If you need some formulas - use tables like .xls or openOffice.

If you still need to modify some value based on others - use Java Arrays / collections for that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the list of data already, can you set the value of the list for D5 to A1 + B2?

A little more detail will help